# How to Calculate Change in Stock percentage Change Value

Tags: mysql

I am maintaining Stock Prices in my Database and this is my database structure

```
CREATE TABLE `sector_wise` (
  `symbol_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sector_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ; 

CREATE TABLE `historical_data` (
  `symbol_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prevclose_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` varchar(30) DEFAULT 'NA'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

**Insert Scripts :**

```
Insert INTO sector_wise ('symbol_name','sector_name') VALUES ('VISESHINFO','Agriculture');



Insert INTO historical_data ('symbol_name','current_day','open_val','high_val','low_val','close_val','last_val','prevclose_val','volume') VALUES ('VISESHINFO','2016-05-03',0.05,0.10,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.10,45814.95);
```

This is the query i tried

```
SELECT sw.symbol_name AS symbol_name,
       hd.current_day AS curr_day,
       hd.open_val AS open_value,
       hd.high_val AS high_value,
       hd.low_val AS low_val,
       hd.close_val AS close_val,
       hd.prevclose_val AS prevclose_val,
       (close_val-prevclose_val)/close_val*100 AS per_change
FROM sector_wise sw,
     historical_data hd
WHERE sw.symbol_name = hd.symbol_name
  AND sw.sector_name = 'Agriculture'
  AND hd.current_day =
    (SELECT max(current_day)
     FROM historical_data)
ORDER BY per_change;
```

The Result i got after executing the above query is which is actually wrong , the percentage chnage should be -50.00 and not -100.00

```
symbol_name  curr_day       open_value   high_value low_value  close_val  prevclose_val percentage_change
VISESHINFO   2016-05-03       0.05           0.10          0.05           0.05         0.10                 -100.000000
```

Could you please tell me where exactly the mistake is in calculating the percentage change

Comment: Where and how are you computing price variation?

Comment: at this line  (close_val-prevclose_val)/close_val*100 AS per_change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(close_val-prevclose_val)/close_val*100 would translate to below:

```
((0.05-0.10)/0.05))*100
```

which is equal to -100. Are you sure of the formula? If it is for price variation, shouldn't the prevclose_val be used in the formula as the denominator?

Comment: this is more of a question on your formula rather than a question of your sql script.

Comment: ya , thanks a lot , the prevclose_val  should be  used in the formula as the denominator

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to do (close_val / prev_close_val) * 100

Answer (score 0):

Having that:
Close value= 0.05
Prev_close value=0.10

```
 Delta = 1-close_value/prev_close
```